# Introduction to Zero Knowledge Proofs for Mathematicians?

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification, cryptography

I'd like to learn more about [Zero Knowledge Proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof) (ZKPs), specifically Non-Interactive ZKPs. However, given that it's a relatively new field seemingly propelled by blockchains, all the introductions I can find are heavily geared towards, use examples in, or assume a background in cryptocurrencies and cryptography.

Are there accessible introductions to ZKPs that are more oriented to those with pure-maths backgrounds?

---

Essentially, I'd like to actually convert some proofs in a simple [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) such as a [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) to a ZKP (preferably non-interactive). Since formal proofs (especially proofs in a propositional calculus, [like this one for $A\implies A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_of_a_proof_in_a_classical_propositional_calculus_system)) are relatively simple objects, I imagine (or hope) that I don't need a huge introduction to theoretical cryptography or blockchain-technologies, like so many introductions seem to suggest, but all the pure-maths examples of ZKPs are either way too simplified (like [the Ali-Baba cave](https://www.byont.io/blog/zero-knowledge-proof-how-it-works-and-the-alibaba-cave-experiment)), or extremely high level (like universal ZKP protocols such as [zk-SNARKs](https://z.cash/technology/zksnarks/)).

So, any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although not directly related to my question, I'd also appreciate any references to examples of some mathematical ZKPs, like [this one for graph isomorphisms](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57675/105986).

Comment: I think the proof of Russell's Paradox might qualify as a ZKP, i.e. it is illogical to assert the existence of a set whose members  are all those, and only those sets which are not members of themselves. It does not matter what "set" and "member" mean. As Russell said, there cannot be a barber who shaves all those and only those who do not shave themselves.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm not so certain Russell's Paradox applies (at least as it is traditionally described), as for me to prove to you that there does not exist a set $R=\{x:x\notin x\}$, I'd have to walk you through a proof by contradiction. Indeed, the proof vacuously is true for any asymmetric relation $\in$, but you do walk out of it with some knowledge of how it is proven / disproven. Maybe you have knowledge of something I don't though (pun intended).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the canonical reference for zero knowledge is [this manuscript.](https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/jthaler/ProofsArgsAndZK.pdf) You may find what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can search up some lecture notes? For example, maybe you can try this: https://crypto.stanford.edu/cs355/18sp/lec3.pdf

Comment: Ah, lecture notes is a good idea. Having read the paper you've linked, it's certainly good introduction! I do wish it were longer, or gave more examples, but I did simply ask an *introduction* I suppose, haha. In any case, perhaps this is part of a series from the author which may lead to something a little more in-depth.

Comment: You can also check some of the notes here: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~mzhandry/courses/2021-Spring-COS533/

There are two lectures on Zero Knowledge